# vboxnet0 interface prevents applications to use Wi-Fi

Tags: linux, virtualbox, network-interface, ifconfig

Since some days ago , a strange interface showed up in my system and is there even when I close Virtualbox :

```
$ ifconfig
...

vboxnet0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vboxnet0:avahi: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.1.79  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
...
```

After some time(maybe a minute) it goes default and causes my entire applications to use that instead of the Wi-Fi interface which is **wlp9s0** :

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.1.79 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

**Note the IP address 169.254.1.79**.

But if I run `ifconfig vboxnet0 down`:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=110 time=95.2 ms
```

But it last for perhaps a minute.

I haven't configured anything about that interface manually and there's no special configuration in my `/etc/netplan/` directory.

And even I cannot delete it:

```
$ sudo ip link delete vboxnet0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

And here's the output of `ip r` in the event of that problem:

```
default dev vboxnet0 scope link metric 1004 linkdown 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp9s0 proto dhcp metric 20600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.1.79 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp9s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.104 metric 600
```

I've been using virtualbox networking for guest OSes for a long time but never encountered such a problem.

By the way I can run something like this:

```
while [ 1 ] ; do  sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 down; sleep 20; done
```

to make sure it won't break anything , but what can I do about that?

BTW I'm using KDE Neon 5.18(= ubuntu 18.04).

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ip r` result, when the problems arises?

Comment: @Krackout Added.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Since it's a desktop setup, I suppose `Network Manager` is installed. Can you check if `vboxnet0` gets handled by `nm`? If yes exclude it.

Comment: Another option would be to remove `vboxnet0`, in case you don't use host-only networking in Virtualbox. Remove it from VBox settings, not using Linux commands. You'll not find out what produced the problem, but it's a solution.

Comment: @Krackout How can I "check if vboxnet0 gets handled by nm" ? I ran ```nmcli device delete vboxnet0``` but it gave me : ```This device is not a software device or is not realized```.

Comment: @Krackout And how can I "Remove it from VBox settings"? Virtualbox is not running at all.In the past when the VBox was down , there wasn't any additional network interface.

Comment: @Krackout And also recently I've noticed that the RX bytes is almost 75MB but TX bytes is around **2.3GB** while I'm not uploaded any large file.Can it be related to that or it's a simple enumeration problem in NM? By the way I haven't rebooted my system for around 12 days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110100/discussion-between-krackout-and-parsa-mousavi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workabout, since you don't use host-only networking, I suggest you delete `vboxnet0` from VBox network settings. That way it will not be available and your problem will be solved.
You can delete it via **File->Host Network Manager->Remove**.